# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class for \d*

Tags: java, regex

My regular expression:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 14
[^]*?￥(\d*.\d*)
              ^
```

But I can't find any flaw in my expression and it works well on `http://regexr.com/`.

My intention for `[^]`:

Use `[^]` to match any character because `.` only match any character except line break.

Call code:

```
Pattern pattern = compile(regex);
```

StackTrace:

```
0 = {StackTraceElement@12872} "java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)"
1 = {StackTraceElement@12873} "java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2548)"
2 = {StackTraceElement@12874} "java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2063)"
3 = {StackTraceElement@12875} "java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)"
4 = {StackTraceElement@12876} "java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1696)"
5 = {StackTraceElement@12877} "java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)"
6 = {StackTraceElement@12878} "java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)" 
...
```

EDIT:

`[^.]*?￥(\d*.\d*)` works. It seems `java.util.regex` doesn't support `[^]` to match any character.

If any one is willing to write some explanation for that, I will accept it as answer.

Comment: @hwnd `[^]` match any character but `.` match any character except line break

Comment: This isn't Javscript ...

Comment: Please provide sample input with expected output so that we can provide you a better regex expression.

Comment: @hwnd: I think your answer applies to this case.

Comment: `[^]` is only valid in JavaScript. In Java, `[^]` is an unclosed character class that negates the character set that matches `]` (plus anything that comes after it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that **you are using the wrong tool to test your regex**. RegExr v2 uses JavaScript regex, while RegExr v1 uses Flex regex, both have different parsing rule compared to Java regex.

While `[^]` is valid in JavaScript, it is parsed as an (incomplete) *negated* character class in Java, which contain literal `]` (and whatever follows).

Java does not accept empty character class (or negated empty character class), so the first `]` in character class (i.e. `[]` or `[^]`) does not close the character class, and `]` is treated as literal character instead.

To make `.` match any character without exception, you might want to use [`Pattern.DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?￥(\\d*.\\d*)", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: What is `unclosed negated character class`, is there any document about that?

Comment: @Sayakiss: `[^]` is not a valid character class in Java by itself, and it needs to be close with another `]`. Java does not accept empty character class (or negated thereof), so `]` at the beginning of the character class will not close the character class, and treated as literal character.